# How to left align the first element and center the rest in 'react-native-snap-carousel'

Tags: react-native, alignment, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

I am trying to make it so the carousel loads aligned left, but once I start swiping, the items are centered (kind of like the 'Suggested Groups' or 'People You May Know' carousels on facebook). So far I got the carousel, but everything is left aligned. Is there any way to make this work with the snap carousel plugin? Here is my code:

```
...
<Carousel
    containerCustomStyle={{paddingLeft: 20, marginTop: 15}}
    data={reviews}
    renderItem={renderCarousel}
    sliderWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
    itemWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width/1.5}
    activeSlideAlignment="start"
/>
...
```

Comment: In my case I was having the same issue but then I added     activeSlideAlignment="start"  it worked.